# Eclipse cannot find main class of maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx

Before you flag this as a duplicate, please note that I have read several other similar questions, but none of them fixed the issue.
I have an Eclipse project using maven. It uses Java 15, with Javafx 13.
When I try to run the app, it has the error message:

> Error: Could not find or load main class app.cleancode.Start

I have tried:

1. refreshing the project,
2. rebuilding from the maven project,
3. and even deleting all of the eclipse files and reimporting the project.

None of them made any difference.

I can run any other project in Eclipse, but this one is just not working.
I am doing this on Windows 10 home.

**My pom file**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>app.cleancode</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-app</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
  <java.version>15</java.version>
  <javafx.version>13</javafx.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${java.version}</release>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3</version>
    <configuration>
    <mainClass>app.cleancode.Start</mainClass>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

app.cleancode.Start:

```
package app.cleancode;

import app.cleancode.game.GameListener;
import app.cleancode.game.GameLoop;
import app.cleancode.game.GameObject;
import app.cleancode.game.PhysicalLaw;
import app.cleancode.game.physics.Gravity;
import app.cleancode.game.physics.Movement;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Start extends Application {
    private static GameListener[] gameListeners = new GameListener[] {
            
    };
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static GameObject<Node> [] gameObjects = new GameObject[] {
            
    };
    private static PhysicalLaw[] laws = new PhysicalLaw[] {
            new Movement(),
            new Gravity()
    };
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
private Pane nodes = new Pane();
 private Pane gamePane = new Pane();
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Scene scene = new Scene(gamePane);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("/app/cleancode/app.css");
    nodes.getChildren().add(new Text("Loading"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Game");
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    primaryStage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(nodes));
    primaryStage.show();
    for(GameListener listener : gameListeners) {
        for(String gameObjectName : listener.getGameObjects()) {
            for(GameObject<Node> gameObject : gameObjects) {
                gameObject.addNode = this::addNode;
                if(gameObject.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(gameObjectName)) {
                    try {
                        var gameObjectField = listener.getClass().getDeclaredField(gameObjectName);
                        gameObjectField.set(listener, gameObject);
                        break;
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        listener.startup();
    }
    scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    GameLoop loop = new GameLoop(this::tick);
    loop.start();
}
public void tick() {
    for(GameListener gameListener : gameListeners) {
        gameListener.update();
    }
    for(PhysicalLaw law : laws) {
        for(GameObject<Node> gameObject : gameObjects) {
            law.handle(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
public void addNode(Node node) {
    gamePane.getChildren().add(node);
}
}
```

** module-info.java **:

```
module app.cleancode.javafx-app {
    exports app.cleancode.axis;
    exports app.cleancode.animation;
    exports app.cleancode;
    exports app.cleancode.sound;
    exports app.cleancode.game.physics;
    exports app.cleancode.bounds;
    exports app.cleancode.game.snake;
    exports app.cleancode.map;
    exports app.cleancode.sprite;
    exports app.cleancode.game;

    requires java.desktop;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.media;
    requires javafx.swing;
}
```

Another piece of information I just found out is that if i create a new Start.java with just a main method, it works fine. Not sure why.

Comment: add the main class after plugin

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Since you have defined app.cleancode.Start as yur main class in the pom file, eclipse is attempting to execute this class when you run your project and is not able to find it. Does your project code contain Start.java. Is this on your classpath. Please include detailed information about your question to be beneficial for the community

Comment: I have added the main class to the post. Thank you for giving me feedback on what to include, as I am new. Let me know if there is anything else I should add.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the easiest solution is to create a new main class that calls the main of the original start.

1. First, rename Start.java to Starter.java (or whatever you want to call it)
2. finally, create a new Start.java in the place of the old one:

Start.java:

```
package app.cleancode;

public class Start {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Starter.main(args);
}
}
```

Then you can just run the new Start.java.